# Stored Procedure changes not reflecting in dacpac script

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, dacpac, sql-server-data-tools

I have added a new stored procedure and added it to my sqlproj file. But when I generate script to publish my database, the changes are not getting reflected in the generated script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the 'Build Action' property of the sql script in the solution explorer..check that its not set to 'None' - from memory it needs to be set to 'Build'

Answer (score 1):

For a stored procedure, following lines must not be there

```
IF EXISTS (...

    DROP PROCEDURE ..
```

Once these lines are removed, set the build action to "Build" and Copy To Output = None

The procedure will then be included in the build script